/proc/diskstats vs iotop and iostats
We're trying to find out why data written on a server has gone up recently, and found a large discrepancy between the values reported by different tools.
Zabbix and /proc/diskstats agree that about 3.6 MBps is being written (it may be that Zabbix gets the information from /proc/diskstats).
On the other hand, iostat and iotop both report about 16 KBps being written at the moment. I notice iostat does report around 3.6 MBps written since system boot, but we're not looking at the amount written since system boot in /proc/diskstats, we're looking at changes to the 10th column (sectors written) now.
What could be the cause of this discrepancy? Could there be something writing to disk that isn't reported by iostat or iotop, and if so what could that be? Thanks in advance.
